# ssh-keygen creates private key with incorrect permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, ssh-keys, umask

When using ssh-keygen without any arguments to generate my ssh keys, it generates both the public and private keys with 644 permissions, making the private key too open to be used. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and my default umask 0002.

```
root@sshkeygen-lgriffin:/home/lgriffin/.ssh# umask
0022
root@sshkeygen-lgriffin:/home/lgriffin/.ssh# ll
total 66
drwx------+  2 lgriffin lgriffin    4 Sep 29 14:22 ./
drwxrwx---+ 19 lgriffin lgriffin   29 Sep 29 14:22 ../
-rw-r-----+  1 lgriffin lgriffin 2622 Sep 29 14:22 id_rsa
-rw-r-----+  1 lgriffin lgriffin  581 Sep 29 14:22 id_rsa.pub
here
```